# Maixmum Principle for Fourth Order Operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain and $\Delta^2=-\Delta\circ(-\Delta)$. If $u\in C^4(\overline{\Omega})$ satisfies $$
\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 \Delta^2u\leq 0 &\mbox{ in $\Omega$} \\
  u=\Delta u=0 &\mbox{ in $\partial\Omega$}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

then, by applying the maximum principle for harmonic functions two times, we can conclude that $u\leq 0$ and $-\Delta u\leq 0$ in $\Omega$. My question is: If now we change $\Delta^2$ in the above system by the operator $\Delta^2+cI$, where $c\geq 0$ is a fixed number and $Iu=u$, can we conclude the same thing?

Comment: Have you tried to construct a one-dimensional counterexample? I'm thinking of something like $u(x)=1-x^4$ on $[-1,1]$, extended smoothly by a negative function on $(-L,-1)\cup (1,L)$, maybe by a spline of high order.

Comment: Yes Pavel, I have tried but with no success. I will try to elaborate your idea.

Comment: @5PM, take a look in this paper (page 62): http://rendiconti.dmi.units.it/volumi/22/04.pdf

Comment: If I understand the paper correctly, the validity of max.principle depends on the size of $c$ relative to the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian there. Sounds reasonable. My tentative counterexample would need sufficiently large $L$ (hence, small $\lambda_1$) to work. // Does the paper answer your question?

Comment: Yes it is a partial answer. Now I need to  know if the bound on $c$ is necessary. What do you think?

Comment: I think it is necessary.

Comment: The bound is necessary @5PM. They prove it in the article (Theorem 2.1.)

Comment: You should post something as an answer, then.